# How to Install R language in Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

How to Install R language in Amazon EC2 instance. I am using Amazon linux in my t2 medium instance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which operating system you are using. If you are using Debian, Ubuntu or something similar, issue the command

```
sudo apt-get -y install r-base
```

You can then start the R system with the command

```
R
```

(keep in mind it's an uppercase R)

Comment: I  have used following command.but it shows no package available. I am using Amazon LInux.                                                                                    $ sudo yum -y install r-base